# std::tolower and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I try to understand how to use `std::tolower`...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "Hello World";
    std::locale loc;
    for (auto &c : test)
    {
        c = std::tolower(c, loc);
    }

    std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), ::tolower); // 1) OK
    std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), std::tolower); // 2) Cryptic compile error
    std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(), static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower)); // 3) Cryptic compile error. Seems OK with other compilers though

    return 0;
}
```

So:

1. Why `::tolower` version is working?
2. Why `std::tolower` is not working in std::transform?
3. What `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower))` really is trying to do? Why
   does it work with GCC and not with Visual Studio 2013?
4. How could I use `std::lower` in std::transform with Visual Studio 2013 then?

Comment: Have you tried including the `<cctype>` header, [which is where `std::tolower` is actually defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)?

Comment: oups, Oo' ^^' But then, why is it working with GCC?

Comment: @Korchkidu, because with GCC one of the other headers you included happens to include `<cctype>`. Never mistake "it happens to work with one compiler" as meaning the code is actually correct, especially with regards to headers including other library headers internally.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: thanks, really clear indeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, note, that **none** of these approaches does the right thing in a portable way! The problem is that `char` may be signed (and typically is) but the versions of `tolower()` only accept positive values! That is you really want to use `std::tolower()` using something like this:

```
std::transform(test.begin(), test.end(), test.begin(),
               [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
```

(or, of course, using a corresponding function object if you are stuck with C++03). Using `std::tolower()` (or `::tolower()` for that matter) with a negative value results in undefined behavior. Of course, this only matters on platform where `char` is signed which seems, however, to be the typical choice.

To answer your questions:

1. When including `<cctype>` you typically get the various functions and types from the standard C library both in namespace `std` as well as in the global namespace. Thus, using `::tolower` normally works but isn't guaranteed to work.
2. When including `<locale>`, there are two versions of `std::tolower` available, one as `int(*)(int)` and one as `char(*)(char, std::locale const&)`. When using just `std::tolower` the compiler has generally no way to decide which one to use.
3. Since `std::tolower` is ambiguous, using `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower)` disambiguates which version to use. Why use of `static_cast<...>()` with VC++ fails, I don't know.
4. You shouldn't use `std::tolower()` with a sequences of `char`s anyway as it will result in undefined behavior. Use a function object using `std::tolower` internally on an `unsigned char`.

It is worth noting that using a function object rather than a function pointer is typically *a lot* faster because it is trivial to inline the function object but not as trivial to inline the function pointer. Compilers are getting better with inlining the use of function pointers where the function is actually known but contemporary compilers certainly don't always inline function calls through function pointers even if all the context would be there.

Comment: I don't know whether this is true of VS2013 too but the docs for VS2012 state that the tolower declared in ctype.h is not safe to use unless isupper returns nonzero, which at face value would mean that using it in a transform would require an explicit test on isupper for every element in the sequence. I know I've certainly seen a load of code that ignores this constraint though so I'm curious to know whether anyone here has any insight into this.

Comment: @Neutrino: This is what the C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011; earlier version said the same as far as I can tell) has to say on this topic in 7.4.2.1 paragraph 3 (Returns): "If the argument is a character for which `isupper` is true and there are one or more
corresponding characters, as specified by the current locale, for which `islower` is true, the `tolower` function returns one of the corresponding characters (always the same one for any given locale); otherwise, the argument is returned unchanged." I don't see any constraint on the argument other than being a valid `unsigned char` value.

Comment: So does Visual Studio adhere to the standard or, as its documentation suggests, does it add an additional non-standard conformant constraint. It states quite clearly here that if isupper does not return true for the argument the results may be 'unexpected' whatever that means. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h19t214.aspx

Comment: @Neutrino: Whether MSVC++ has a standard conforming implemention of `tolower` I don't know. I would assume they do, however.

Answer (score 7):

`std::tolower` is overloaded in C++, it's declared in `<cctype>` as

```
int tolower(int);
```

and also in `<locale>` as

```
template<CharT> CharT tolower(CharT, const locale&);
```

so when you say "`std::tolower`" you get an ambiguous reference to an overloaded function.

> 1. Why `::tolower` version is working?

When you include `<cctype>` the one-argument overload is declared in namespace `std` and *might* also be declared in the global namespace, depending on the compiler.   If you include `<ctype.h>` then it's guaranteed to be included in the global namespace, and `::tolower` will work (although note Dietmar's points about when it's not safe). The two-argument overload from `<locale>` is never declared in the global namespace, so `::tolower` never refers to the two-argument overload.

> 2. Why `std::tolower` is not working in std::transform?

See above, it's an overloaded name.

> 3. What `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(std::tolower))` really is trying to do?

It tells the compiler you want the `int std::tolower(int)` overload, not any other overload of `std::tolower`.

> Why does it work with GCC and not with Visual Studio 2013?

Probably because you didn't include `<cctype>`, or (less likely) it could be a Visual Studio bug.

> 4. How could I use `std::lower` in `std::transform` with Visual Studio 2013 then?

If you know you only have characters with values between 0 and 127 then you can include `<ctype.h>` and use `::tolower` (because the two-argument version is not declared in the global namespace, only in namespace `std`) or disambiguate which overload you want with the static cast.  An alternative to the cast is to use a local variable:

```
typedef int (*tolower_type)(int);
tolower_type tl = &std::tolower;
std::transform(b, e, b, tl);
```

A safer and portable alternative is to use a custom function object (or lambda expression) to call the desired overload safely:

```
std::transform(b, e, b, [](unsigned char i) { return std::tolower(i); });
```

This uses `std::tolower` with an argument, so the compiler can do overload resolution to tell which overload you want to call.  The parameter is `unsigned char` to ensure we never pass a `char` with a negative value to `tolower(int)`, because that has undefined behaviour.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/strings.html#strings.string.simple for more details.

Comment: You should know better than advising people to use the `<cctype>` functions with `char`s!