# get vowels from char in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char a[20];

int main()
{
    cin >> a;
}
```

If I write for a="home", I want to take the vowels ("o" and "e") and replace them with capital letters ("O" and "E"). how do I do that?

EDIT:
Your answers where very helpful. I did something like this:

```
    cin >> a;

for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && i <= 20; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == 'a')
        a[i] = 'A';
    if (a[i] == 'e')
        a[i] = 'eE';
    if (a[i] == 'i')
        a[i] = 'iI';
    if (a[i] == 'o')
        a[i] = 'oO';
    if (a[i] == 'u')
        a[i] = 'uU';

}
```

I wanted to change for exemple "e" into "eE" but it doesn't work...

Comment: Start with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876746/stdtolower-and-visual-studio-2013) and add in `isvowel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char a[20];

int main(){
    cin >> a;
    for (int i = 0; a[i] != '\0' && i < 20; i++){
        if (a[i] == 'a' || a[i] == 'e' || a[i] == 'i'|| a[i] == 'o'|| a[i] == 'u'){
            a[i] = a[i] + 'A' - 'a';
        }
    }
    cout << a;
}
```

The program iterates each character in the string, and compares it to all five vowels. If it finds it is a vowel, it turns it into uppercase.

The line

```
a[i] = a[i] + 'A' - 'a';
```

may seem hard to understand, but it isn't. Every character is actually an integer in a coding system. In most coding systems, the difference between a letter and its corresponding capital letter is a constant given by ('A' - 'a'). So, by adding ('A' - 'a') to any character, you effectively turn it into uppercase.

Comment: I don't think SO is a place where ready made is supplied to the OP who has not shown his effort and contribution towards the question !

Comment: and if i want to change a[i] into more letters?

Comment: You mean substitute a[i] with two or more letters?

Comment: That would be more complicated, because a[i] only holds one character. If you wanted to substitute it with two characters you would have to change a[i] and a[i+1], and push all the characters to the right.

Answer (score 5):

1. Write a function which will tell you whether something is a vowel or not.  This can be as simple as looping through an array or using [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/).
2. Iterate through the characters and replace the vowels with the return value of [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/).

As a secondary note, you probably want to use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) instead of `char[]`.

Comment: 1. sounds good, i just don't know how? using ascii? i don't even know how to take all the letters from a one by one...

Comment: I don't think SO is a place where ready made code is supplied to the OP who has not shown his effort and contribution towards the question !

Comment: @KaustavRay, This is borderline. When the idea is sufficiently simple that showing the code is instructive, I think it helps more than it hurts.

Comment: @KaustavRay, Also, the code post is secondary, addressing the OP's clarifying comment.

Comment: I think the original answer (sans code) was excellent, we can only hope that the poster tries to learn from it, rather than cut and pasting the ready-made code.

Comment: @MattCoubrough, It is definitely borderline so I will take your feedback. Do you want me to delete the code?

Comment: The idea may be sufficiently simple for you but not for everybody ! and please just compare what user's code snippet and the one you posted as answer. The user is knowing only how to input the string and nothing after that ! But you provided the whole code anyway !

Comment: @MattCoubrough, I guess it's too late since the accepted answer is a pure-code answer. But this means you were corect.

Comment: @KaustavRay, Very fair point. I will be more conservative in the future.

Comment: Yeah kind of frustrating when this happens isn't it? We're creating a breed of programmers whose first action when faced with a challenge is to get other people to write their code on Stack Overflow :(

Comment: @MattCoubrough, I have deleted the code to show a better model for answering questions.

Comment: I'm not against code in solutions at all @merlin2011 - and I didn't really mind that you added a snippet either, I'm just against people using Stack Overflow as a code writing and debugging service!

Comment: @MattCoubrough, I concur.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //inside the loop body

   cin >> a;
   while(a[i])
   if(a[i] == 'a' || a[i] == 'e' || a[i] == 'i' || a[i]== 'o' || a[i]=='u')
   {
         a[i]=toupper(a[i]);
   }
```

Comment: You might consider removing your answer as it is wrong   !

Comment: I thought you read individual chars ( something like getchar)...anyways just refer new answer...